# Can a hive script be run from another hive script?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I have created two hive scripts script1.hql and script2.hql.

Is it possible to run the script script2.hql from script1.hql?

I read about using the source command, but could not get around about its use.
Any pointers/ref docs will be appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `source  <filepath>` command:

```
source /tmp/script2.hql; --inside script1
```

The docs are here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli

Hive will include text of /tmp/script2.hql and execute it in the same context, so all variables defined for main script will be accessible script2 commands.

`source` command looks for local path (not HDFS). Copy file to local directory before executing.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will the hivevars passed to script1.hql will automatically be available to script2.hql?

Comment: @Djeah Sure  hivevars passed to script1.hql will automatically be available to script2.hql .

Answer (score -1):

Try using command and see if you can execute

```
hive -f /home/user/sample.sql
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. This executes one script, not two