# How to substitue variables in beeline HQL script

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, beeline

I am trying to execute a beeline hql file with the following contents.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY "${hadoop_temp_output_dir}${file_pattern}${business_date}"  select data from  database.${table}
```

I am executing the script using the following command:

```
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://svr.us.XXXX.net:10000/;principal=hive/svr.us.XXXX.net@NAEAST.COM" --hivevar hadoop_temp_output_dir=/tenants/demo/hive/database/ --hivevar file_pattern=sales --hivevar business_date=20180709  -f beeline_test.hql
```

I see the variables are not getting substituted while they are getting executed in the hive environment. What is the mistake I made here.
Also, how to setup init.hql(for all configurations) and execute this hql file

EDIT:I got the answer: I just used double quotes for the variables and corrected few typos

Comment: better use namespace:variable notation. Like this: ${hivevar:hadoop_temp_output_dir}

Comment: I have edited my answer and got it working. Also I would like to know how to pass them as part of init script

Comment: I am more interested in knowing about how to use init script. I have not found any good artciles on that.

Comment: using `source ` command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49536563/2700344 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39309609/2700344

Comment: Thanks. When do we use beeline -i (initialization script) ? and how to use

Comment: The above doesn't work for me. the query comes out of the prompt after sourcing the file.

Comment: If you have found the answer, put it below rather than edit the question, please